# Long footnote stretches out width of columns

Tags: tables, line-breaking, footnotes

I'm new to LaTeX and ran into a problem with formatting my table. I would like to have a long footnote underneath the table that starts a new line as soon as it reaches the border of the last column of the table. However, when I put in the footnote, the last column of the table stretches out as far as the footnote goes. Anyone that could help me out?

This is my full code:

````
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[margin=100pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!htbp]\centering
\renewcommand\thetable{2}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\caption{ESG and corporate bond spreads\label{tab1}}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{l*{5}{c}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{(5)}\\
                    &\multicolumn{1}{c}{Panel OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Panel OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{OLS}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{IV}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{Panel OLS}\\
\midrule
ESG score           &      -0.296\sym{***}&                     &      -0.389\sym{**} &     -0.0137         &     -0.0460         \\
                    &     (0.101)         &                     &     (0.197)         &     (0.227)         &    (0.0979)         \\
\addlinespace
Environment score   &                     &      0.0925         &                     &                     &                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0731)         &                     &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
Social score        &                     &      -0.332\sym{***}&                     &                     &                     \\
                    &                     &     (0.102)         &                     &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
Governance score    &                     &     -0.0974         &                     &                     &                     \\
                    &                     &    (0.0675)         &                     &                     &                     \\
\addlinespace
Firm size           &       4.508\sym{**} &       3.667         &       8.245\sym{**} &       1.517         &      -1.274         \\
                    &     (2.287)         &     (2.270)         &     (3.700)         &     (2.928)         &     (2.852)         \\
\addlinespace
Capital intensity   &       0.226         &       0.155         &       0.141         &      -0.145         &       0.272\sym{**} \\
                    &     (0.176)         &     (0.188)         &     (0.168)         &     (0.109)         &     (0.129)         \\
\addlinespace
Market-to-book      &       0.103\sym{***}&       0.116\sym{***}&       0.166         &      0.0624         &      0.0506         \\
                    &    (0.0366)         &    (0.0366)         &     (0.149)         &    (0.0616)         &    (0.0347)         \\
\addlinespace
Leverage            &      -0.236         &      -0.195         &      -0.112         &       0.185         &      -0.337\sym{**} \\
                    &     (0.184)         &     (0.183)         &     (0.179)         &     (0.125)         &     (0.149)         \\
\addlinespace
ROA                 &      -0.924\sym{***}&      -0.862\sym{***}&      -0.534         &      -0.240         &      -0.165         \\
                    &     (0.308)         &     (0.299)         &     (0.511)         &     (0.261)         &     (0.212)         \\
\addlinespace
Interest coverage ratio&      -0.521         &      -0.561         &      -0.919\sym{*}  &      -0.237         &     -0.0974         \\
                    &     (0.431)         &     (0.441)         &     (0.479)         &     (0.270)         &     (0.210)         \\
\addlinespace
Callable(1=yes)     &       20.43\sym{***}&       19.69\sym{***}&       8.305         &       13.57\sym{*}  &       13.26\sym{***}\\
                    &     (6.391)         &     (6.583)         &     (10.64)         &     (7.356)         &     (4.364)         \\
\addlinespace
Green bond(1=yes)   &      -2.342         &      -2.322         &       4.679         &       4.291         &      -17.63\sym{***}\\
                    &     (11.20)         &     (10.67)         &     (17.82)         &     (13.12)         &     (4.702)         \\
\addlinespace
Rank                &      -7.580\sym{***}&      -7.650\sym{***}&      -10.41\sym{***}&      -11.76\sym{***}&       0.372         \\
                    &     (1.876)         &     (1.847)         &     (1.170)         &     (0.653)         &     (1.976)         \\
\addlinespace
Tenor(in years)     &       1.356\sym{***}&       1.359\sym{***}&       1.267\sym{***}&       1.600\sym{***}&       2.152\sym{***}\\
                    &     (0.279)         &     (0.275)         &     (0.488)         &     (0.286)         &     (0.197)         \\
\addlinespace
Amount              &       1.237         &       0.480         &       5.942         &       1.454         &       1.084         \\
                    &     (3.109)         &     (3.086)         &     (6.669)         &     (3.123)         &     (2.592)         \\
\addlinespace
Year FE             &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\addlinespace
Country FE          &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\addlinespace
Asset-type FE       &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         &         Yes         \\
\addlinespace
Firm FE             &          No         &          No         &          No         &          No         &         Yes         \\
\midrule
Observations        &        1284         &        1284         &         267         &         997         &        1261         \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &       0.592         &       0.595         &       0.584         &       0.662       &       0.779         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in parentheses}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize In column 1 and 2, the full sample of firms with an ESG score is used. In column 3, the sample at origination is used. In column 4, the full sample is used in an IV regression. In column 5, the full sample is used in a regression including firm fixed effects}\\
\multicolumn{6}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\end{document}```
````

Comment: I used the article class. Forgot to put that line in as well

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 3):

The `threeparttable` environment recognizes three formal components: the caption, a `tabular` (or `tabular*`, `tabularx`, `tabulary`) environment, and a `tablenotes` environment. The `threeparttable` machinery limits the widths of the caption and of the `tablesnotes` material to that of the `tabular` environment. I thus recommend you move the three lines that are currently at the bottom of the `tabular` environment into a new `tablenotes` environment.

I would also like to recommend you align the numbers in the 5 data columns on their respective decimal markers. This may be achieved with the help of the `dcolumn` package. See below for an application.

Given the size of the text block, having `\addlinespace` instructions after every pair of rows makes the full `table` too tall. I suggest you insert `\addlinespace` after every fourth pair of rows only.

Oh, and do get rid of the `adjustbox` stuff. Placing the tabular material inside an `adjustbox` environment virtually *guarantees* that the font size in the table will be wildly inconsistent with that in the rest of the document.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[margin=100pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

%% New instructions:
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D..{#1}}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}    % handy shortcut macros
\newcommand\mcc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c@{}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{1} % just for this example
\begin{table}[p] % place this float on a page by itself
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
%% First formal component: the caption
\caption{ESG and corporate bond spreads}\label{tab1}
%% Second formal component: the 'tabular' environment
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{5}{d{3.5}} @{}}
\toprule
&\mc{(1)}&\mc{(2)}&\mc{(3)}&\mc{(4)}&\mcc{(5)}\\
&\mc{Panel OLS}&\mc{Panel OLS}&\mc{OLS}&\mc{IV}&\mcc{Panel OLS}\\
\midrule
ESG score           & -0.296\sym{***}&                & -0.389\sym{**} &-0.0137         &-0.0460         \\
                    &(0.101)         &                &(0.197)         &(0.227)         &(0.0979)        \\
Environment score   &                & 0.0925         &                &                &                \\
                    &                &(0.0731)        &                &                &                \\
Social score        &                & -0.332\sym{***}&                &                &                \\
                    &                &(0.102)         &                &                &                \\
Governance score    &                &-0.0974         &                &                &                \\
                    &                &(0.0675)        &                &                &                \\
\addlinespace
Firm size           &  4.508\sym{**} &  3.667         &  8.245\sym{**} &  1.517         & -1.274         \\
                    &(2.287)         &(2.270)         &(3.700)         &(2.928)         &(2.852)         \\
Capital intensity   &  0.226         &  0.155         &  0.141         & -0.145         &  0.272\sym{**} \\
                    &(0.176)         &(0.188)         &(0.168)         &(0.109)         &(0.129)         \\
Market-to-book      &  0.103\sym{***}&  0.116\sym{***}&  0.166         & 0.0624         & 0.0506         \\
                    & (0.0366)       &(0.0366)        &(0.149)         &(0.0616)        &(0.0347)        \\
Leverage            & -0.236         & -0.195         & -0.112         &  0.185         & -0.337\sym{**} \\
                    &(0.184)         &(0.183)         &(0.179)         &(0.125)         &(0.149)         \\
\addlinespace
ROA                 & -0.924\sym{***}& -0.862\sym{***}& -0.534         & -0.240         & -0.165         \\
                    &(0.308)         &(0.299)         &(0.511)         &(0.261)         &(0.212)         \\
Interest coverage ratio& -0.521      & -0.561         & -0.919\sym{*}  & -0.237         &-0.0974         \\
                    &(0.431)         &(0.441)         &(0.479)         &(0.270)         &(0.210)         \\
Callable (1=yes)    &  20.43\sym{***}&  19.69\sym{***}&  8.305         &  13.57\sym{*}  &  13.26\sym{***}\\
                    &(6.391)         &(6.583)         &(10.64)         &(7.356)         &(4.364)         \\
Green bond (1=yes)  & -2.342         & -2.322         &  4.679         &  4.291         & -17.63\sym{***}\\
                    &(11.20)         &(10.67)         &(17.82)         &(13.12)         &(4.702)         \\
\addlinespace
Rank                & -7.580\sym{***}& -7.650\sym{***}& -10.41\sym{***}& -11.76\sym{***}&  0.372         \\
                    &(1.876)         &(1.847)         &(1.170)         &(0.653)         &(1.976)         \\
Tenor (in years)    &  1.356\sym{***}&  1.359\sym{***}&  1.267\sym{***}&  1.600\sym{***}&  2.152\sym{***}\\
                    &(0.279)         &(0.275)         &(0.488)         &(0.286)         &(0.197)         \\
Amount              &  1.237         &  0.480         &  5.942         &  1.454         &  1.084         \\
                    &(3.109)         &(3.086)         &(6.669)         &(3.123)         &(2.592)         \\
\addlinespace
Year FE             &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mcc{Yes}       \\
Country FE          &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mcc{Yes}       \\
Asset-type FE       &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mc{Yes}        &\mcc{Yes}       \\
Firm FE             & \mc{No}        & \mc{No}        & \mc{No}        & \mc{No}        &\mcc{Yes}       \\
\midrule
Observations        &\mc{1284}       &\mc{1284}       &\mc{267}        &\mc{997}        &\mcc{1261}      \\
Adjusted \(R^{2}\)  &\mc{0.592}      & \mc{0.595}     &\mc{0.584 }     &\mc{0.662}      &\mcc{0.779}     \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% The third formal component: the 'tablenotes' environment
\smallskip\footnotesize
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[1]Standard errors in parentheses.
\item[2]In columns 1 and 2, the full sample of firms with an ESG score is used. In column 3, the sample at origination is used. In column 4, the full sample is used in an IV regression. In column 5, the full sample is used in a regression including firm fixed effects.
\item[3]Statistical significance indicators: $\sym{*}\ p<0.10,\ \sym{**}\ p<0.05,\ \sym{***}\ p<0.01$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works perfectly. Really appreciate the effort. I do have one additional question perhaps. Is it possible to remove the numbering of the footnotes?

Comment: @Jerome - You're most welcome. On your follow-up question: just write `\item[]` instead of `\item[1]`, `\item[2]`, etc.

Comment: Super, got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does this meet the requirement

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \caption{Sample ANOVA table}
     \begin{tabular}{lllll}
        \toprule
        Stubhead & \( df \) & \( f \) & \( \eta \) & \( p \) \\
        \midrule
                 &     \multicolumn{4}{c}{Spanning text}     \\
        Row 1    & 1        & 0.67    & 0.55       & 0.41    \\
        Row 2    & 2        & 0.02    & 0.01       & 0.39    \\
        Row 3    & 3 \tnote{a}       & 0.15    & 0.33       & 0.34    \\
        Row 4    & 4        & 1.00    & 0.76       & 0.54    \\
        \bottomrule
     \end{tabular}
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \small
      \item [a]This is where authors provide additional information about
      the data, including whatever notes are needed.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, I cannot get this to work. I get an error saying 'Missing \endgroup inserted'.

Comment: go with the lovely answer by @Mico